# How to get the wordlist from youtube search for Jquery UI autocomplete?

Tags: jquery, search, autocomplete, youtube, youtube-api

I just builded [my own youtube search](http://neocsatblog.mblx.hu/youtubetest.php) based on [Youtube API V3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list?hl=hu).
I would like to add auto complete function to search input, the problem is, the wordlist.
If I add a big word list, that means a bigger load time, and the autocomplete is useless, because you need to write out the full word, for get your correct word, if I add a small wordlist, the load time is good, but the problem is same, the autocomplete is useless, because dosen't complete any useful.
So I looked this problem in a different way.
What about if I somehow I get the youtube autocomplete wordlist, based on relevance, and the wordlist only then loaded, when you typing.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

With so many research I found a solution for this:

```
$("#q").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response){
        /* Need a api key for this, so we add it:  */
        var apiKey = 'MYAPIKEY';
        /* command */
        var query = request.term;
        /* youtube ajax request */
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?hl=en&ds=yt&client=youtube&hjson=t&cp=1&q="+query+"&key="+apiKey+"&format=5&alt=json&callback=?",  
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(data, textStatus, request) { 
               response( $.map( data[1], function(item) {
                    return {
                        label: item[0],
                        value: item[0]
                    }
                }));
            }
        });
    },
    /* seçilene işlem yapmak için burayı kullanabilirsin */
    select: function( event, ui ) {

    }
});
```

I hope it help also someone else who looking for a something like this.