# How to categorize jQuery UI-autocomplete with YouTube's categories

Tags: jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using **jQuery UI-autocomplete** to get wordlist from YouTube, I used the code proposed here: [How to get the wordlist from youtube search for Jquery UI autocomplete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30469590/how-to-get-the-wordlist-from-youtube-search-for-jquery-ui-autocomplete)

I wanted to know if it is possible to autocomplete from YouTube by categories, for example, category music of YouTube.

```javascript
$("#q").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response){
        /* Need a api key for this, so we add it:  */
        var apiKey = 'MYAPIKEY';
        /* command */
        var query = request.term;
        /* youtube ajax request */
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?hl=en&ds=yt&client=youtube&hjson=t&cp=1&q="+query+"&key="+apiKey+"&format=5&alt=json&callback=?",  
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(data, textStatus, request) { 
               response( $.map( data[1], function(item) {
                    return {
                        label: item[0],
                        value: item[0]
                    }
                }));
            }
        });
    },
    /* seçilene işlem yapmak için burayı kullanabilirsin */
    select: function( event, ui ) {

    }
});
```